# Trying to create chrome extension to hide iframe content from a page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, null, pageload

im working to create a very simple chrome extension just to remove an annoying tag from a site here is my codes

my manifest.json file include those lines :

{
    "manifest_version": 2,

```
"name": "RemoveMysatgoHelp",
"description": "Remove Mysatgo Help tag",
"version": "1.0",

"icons": {
    "16": "imgs/16.png",
    "32": "imgs/32.png",
    "64": "imgs/64.png",        
    "128": "imgs/128.png"
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "*://*.mysatgo.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
]
```

}

my content.js file include this single line:

```
var elements0 = document.getElementById('launcher');
elements0.style.display='none';
```

i need to remove these "Help window"at the bottom of the page it disturbing the main player control, here is my illustration https://prnt.sc/qaeaf5

i believe it is a dynamic tag inside an anonymous div tag ,the only id name that we have is within the iframe tag and the idname is "launcher"

my question

the problem again the elements0 return null ,because it seems the page not fully loaded with all the sources

any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `"js"` and the content script. Instead use `"css"` and a css file with a rule like #launcher { display: none !important }

Comment: Thanks Dear , done i removed the js file and i added a css file